# Do Custom Labels created by managed packages count against an Org's limit of 5,000 Custom Labels?

Tags: managed-package, limits, customlabel

As of Winter '14, Salesforce imposes a limit of 5,000 [Custom Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en) per Org.  That sounds like a lot, and would be for most Orgs, but I've noticed that many managed packages create a LOT of Custom Labels once they're installed.

Here is what I'd like to know:

Do the Custom Labels that are created by managed packages count against an Org's 5,000 limit, or is this particular limit "scoped" to that package in a manner similar to how [Certified Managed Packages](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm#certified_pkg_limits_section) get their own sets of certain governor limits?

Comment: An educated guess tells me that custom labels would be namespace scoped, because otherwise that could cripple ISVs that actually care about multi-lingual sales, but I cannot find any clear documentation on the matter.

Comment: @sfdcfox good point about the ISVs.  I think you're right, but I found the lack of clarity in the Salesforce docs disturbing enough to hope that someone from SF might see this and give us clarity.  :-)  Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: I'm going to find the answer for this and make sure it gets doc'd.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Salesforce dev here. Labels from managed packages do not count against the 5000 label limit.

Thanks for raising this doc gap; we'll get it updated.

Comment: Welcome Carolyn to SE!

Comment: While you're at it, do you happen to know if this is a limit that can be upped for a pkg via black tab, or something that's really a hard limit?

Comment: Thanks, Carolyn! I'm thrilled to know that you guys are reading the Salesforce SE!  :-)

Comment: @ca_peterson Hard limit.

Comment: Turns out it is in fact a soft limit after all. If you ask really nicely you can go over 5k labels in a namesapce.